# Are contracting questions on-topic at Freelancing?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask some questions about IT contracting, but I thought it would be worth checking to see if they are on-topic at *Freelancing*. I can't see that this has specifically been asked on the Meta site yet.

In case the word means things in different regions, by "contracting" I mean a fixed-duration working relationship set up between a worker and a client, often with a recruiter arranging the introduction, and with no permanent employment benefits offered.

Contractors work on a daily rate rather than on a fixed/project cost basis, and - at least here in the UK - tend to set up a limited company rather than as a self tax-assessing sole trader. Contractors work only at one company at once, and usually on-site, but still regard themselves as self-employed.

Questions relating to contracting might include how to deal with recruitment agencies, contractual terms that one sets up with recruiters, as well as how to choose and set up country-specific company vehicles for the purposes of paying wages and taxation.

Comment: Ah, the site Tour doesn't mention contracting, but [this answer](http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/a/76/8370) seems to think it's on-topic.

Comment: There are [a number of questions relating to recruiters](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search?q=recruiter), which perhaps would also support the view that contracting questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Contracting is definitely on-topic here, but I'd say we should stay away from agency work with a 15ft pole (it's employment via a third-party company).

That's not to say we *shouldn't* allow questions/answers from people who are contracting via an agency, just that we should probably not have questions **specific** to agencies.

A few points:

- There's quite a few questions about [contracts](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts) here
- We're a site for freelance and self-employed workers
- By definition, a freelancer should actually be a contractor
- Contractors are almost universally freelancers.
- We could do with a few questions about disguised employment (how to avoid it, etc.)

In addition, it's actually recommended to incorporate as a freelancer in the UK, because you then don't have unlimited liability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I think I might have accidentally given the impression I'm interested in asking about agency employment - I'm not. All IT contracting work I am looking at is offered by recruiters, who take a cut of the daily rate. However the contractor is not employed by the recruiter or an agency. (I may appear to be labouring the point, but in fact I just want to ensure I don't ask a question that accidentally violates the 'no agency work' posting rule because we understand the terminology differently).

Comment: @halfer IT contract work, regardless of if a recruiter arranges it, is still *technically* freelancing. You still do a self-assessment tax return, so you're still self-employed. You may technically be in disguised employment though, which is something I'd probably say was on-topic (that could be another question, though)

Comment: Alright, thanks Amelia. Interesting that our understanding of 'contractor' diverges here - I have a number of friends who undertake the activity I have described, and they call themselves contractors.

Comment: @halfer I work for a company that recruits contractors and takes a margin, and I think we have exactly the same definition. Contractor and Freelancer are near-identical in meaning, and I think we shouldn't really differentiate them here

Comment: I can agree with that, but you suggested that 'consultants' was a better word for what I had described?

Comment: @halfer "consultant" is usually used for a day-rate contractor in IT charging a premium, but not always, probably as a marketing tactic. It's usually for people who come in and fix things or implement a system then leave, and charge 3-4x more.

Comment: Ah right, I see what you mean. I'm talking about day-rate individuals, undertaking a period of one to 12 months, at say £200-£400 per day.